how to center background image added by image sprites


.social-media-icon{
            display: inline-block;
    
            }
    
            .social-media-icon a{
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                border: 2px solid #c3d4e2;  
                position: relative;
                    
                height: 36px;
                width: 36px;
                background: url(/img/social-icons.png) ;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: 50%;
    
            }
            .social-media-icon a:hover{
                background-color: #c3d4e2;
            }
    
            .fb-icon a{
                background-position:  0 0 ; 
    
            }
            .fb-icon a:hover{
                background-position: 0 -36px;
            }
    
            .x-icon a{
                background-position:-36px 0 ; 
            }
    
            .x-icon a:hover{
                background-position: -36px -36px ; 
            }
    
            .youtube-icon a{
                background-position: -72px 0 ; 
            }
            .youtube-icon a:hover{
                background-position: -72px -36px ; 
            }
    
            .insta-icon a{
                background-position: -108px 0 ; 
            }
            .insta-icon a:hover{
                background-position: -108px -36px ; 
            }
<div class="social-media">
<div class="fb-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">

        <span class="social-text">fb</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="x-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">x</span> 
    </a>
</div>
<div class="youtube-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">youtube</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="insta-icon social-media-icon icon">   
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">intergram</span>
     </a>
</div>



This code snippet is for creating background images using image sprites. when hovering over the image that background image should change.
I want to center those social media icons in that div element. I tried background-position: center center but it didn't work. Here I attached an output of the above code snippet. That isn't centered properly. What can I do to center all images in each div elements

This is the main image

You need to adjust the background-position for all the icons.


.social-media-icon{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.social-media-icon a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    border: 2px solid #c3d4e2;  

    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    background: url(https://i.sstatic.net/eSmLc9vI.png);

}
.social-media-icon a:hover{
    background-color: #c3d4e2;
}

.fb-icon a{
    background-position: 2px 2px; 

}
.fb-icon a:hover{
    background-position: 2px 2px;
}

.x-icon a{
    background-position:-36px 0 ; 
}

.x-icon a:hover{
    background-position: -36px -36px ; 
}

.youtube-icon a{
    background-position: -71px 2px ; 
}
.youtube-icon a:hover{
    background-position: -71px -34px ; 
}

.insta-icon a{
    background-position: -106px 2px ; 
}
.insta-icon a:hover{
    background-position: -106px -34px ; 
}
<div class="social-media">
<div class="fb-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">

        <span class="social-text">fb</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="x-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">x</span> 
    </a>
</div>
<div class="youtube-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">youtube</span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="insta-icon social-media-icon icon">   
    <a href="">
        <span class="social-text">intergram</span>
     </a>
</div>




Here is a better way to code it using more generic values but you may have to edit the image because the icons inside the image aren't perfectly centered. it's not a CSS issue.


.social-media-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.social-media-icon a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 36px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #c3d4e2;
  background: 
    url(https://i.sstatic.net/eSmLc9vI.png) content-box
    var(--x) var(--y,0%) / 400% 200%, var(--c,#0000);
}
.social-media-icon a:hover {
  --y:100%;
  --c:#c3d4e2;
}
.fb-icon a      {--x:calc(000%/3)} /* 0% */
.x-icon a       {--x:calc(100%/3)} /* 33.3% */
.youtube-icon a {--x:calc(200%/3)} /* 66.7% */
.insta-icon a   {--x:calc(300%/3)} /* 100% */
<div class="social-media">
  <div class="fb-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">

      <span class="social-text">fb</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="x-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
      <span class="social-text">x</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="youtube-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
      <span class="social-text">youtube</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="insta-icon social-media-icon icon">
    <a href="">
      <span class="social-text">intergram</span>
    </a>
  </div>




still not centered the instergram image in your answer.
